# Class org.gradle.tooling.internal.gradle.DefaultBuildIdentifier does not implement the requested interface

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I have reinstalled Android Studio on Ubuntu 20.04. I've received error: "Minimum supported Gradle version is 4.10.1. Current version is 4.4.1."

But when I try to update gradle to any newer version, I receive output:

> Starting Gradle Daemon...
>
> Gradle Daemon started in 531 ms
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>
> Failed to notify build listener.
>
> Class org.gradle.tooling.internal.gradle.DefaultBuildIdentifier does not implement the requested interface org.gradle.tooling.model.BuildIdentifier

I've tryed Android Gradle Plugin Version 4.0.1 and Gradle Version 6.6.1 and several older versions with the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed and reinstalled android studio once more. Got error: "Could not create parent directory for lock file <*my gradle wrapper location>". Checked access rights for gradle wrapper location and noticed, that some directories were owned by root. I changed owner for these directories. It helped: the next build was successfull.